# Drush Config Export not working after Site-install Standard

Tags: 8, installation, configuration

I have a Drupal starter site created and pushed to bitbucket. For every new project I start I clone this site and start working from there. It worked for a while but I'm trying to get it to work for a new site and I can't.

The Drupal starter is running Drupal 8.5.3 and I am using Drush 9 on my machine. To get the clone to work I do the following:

`git clone https://example@bitbucket.org/example/[repo].git`

`git checkout dev` (my working branch)

`composer install`

`cd web` (drupal root)

`drush site-install standard --db-url=mysql://{db_usr}:{db_pass}@localhost/{db_name} --config-dir=../config/sync`

After the install the configuration is imported automatically and that is where it is going wrong. I get the following error:

`[error]  Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 736 of /web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php). 
 [error]  The import failed due to the following reasons:
Unable to install the <em class="placeholder">standard</em> module since it does not exist.
Unable to uninstall the <em class="placeholder">Minimal</em> profile since it is the install profile.
Cannot change the install profile from <em class="placeholder">minimal</em> to <em class="placeholder">standard</em> once Drupal is installed.`

So looking in to this error I find the following thread [#278877](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2788777). But this patch doesn't seem to work for me.

What I tried is to install the site, after the `composer install`, via the browser. And for some reason this does work.

I know I can do it via the browser from now on, but I really want to know what is going wrong. I prefer to use command-line over the browser.

Something else I noticed is that in the `settings.php` file, after installation, there is a line with `$settings['install_profile']` the value of this setting is **'minimal'** when using the `drush site-install` even when I'm saying it should use the standard option. When I use the installation via the browser the value is **'standard'** and for this reason does work.

I tried changing the `settings.php` from minimal to standard manually. And tried changing the `core.extensions` config file as mentioned in some other threads I found but nothing works. Bij core.extensions file is not the problem I think both the `standard: 1000` and `profile: standard` are there.

Am I doing something wrong? Has something changed since drupal 8.5 or drush 9 (instead of drush 8 - I just updated)? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you confirm the site you setup via browser install standard profile and not minimal profile?

Comment: Yes via Browser I choose standard.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is standard profile path in the "installer-paths" section of the composer.json

Comment: No, this is all there is:
`"web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],"web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],"web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],"web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],"web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],"drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]`

Comment: I think the change is https://www.drupal.org/node/2538996
Not 100% sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand this change record. What I understand is that the installation profile shouldn't be in the settings.php but when I do a clean install of the most currect versions of Drupal (8.5.3) it is still there and nothing looks much different from the files I have in my starter. Can you explain me a bit more about what is wrong ik my starter site, and what to change to make it work again?